# Open new window on grid view button click in aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on aspx.cs page.When i will click on grid button column,then it should be take some data from present page to new page and open it in to new window without destroy present window.

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "Trans")
    {

      Response.Redirect("APIwiserecharge.aspx?DisplayID=" +
       objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
    }

  }
```

Comment: So you want use an updatePanel for showing the data?

Comment: No sir, I want to open a new ASPX page..

Answer (score 1):

To open a new window from codebehind you need to use javascript. You need to handle click event with javascript. You can try this code for your codebehind:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "Trans")
    {

       string url = "APIwiserecharge.aspx?DisplayID=" +objdl.Encode(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

       string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Its not working.So please send me the otherone.PLEASE .

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open( 'APIwiserecharge.aspx','_blank','height=600px,width=600px,scrollbars=1');", true);
```